# The JS arent working on my Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

so, i get that form HTML template: 
https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/rxddKy

but after implemented, it arent working ):

The login View:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div> <% end %>


<div class="login-page">   <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="Senha"/>
      <button>Cadastrar</button>
      <p class="message">Já é registrado? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" action="/login/acessorecebendo" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Não está registrado <a href="#">Criar uma conta</a></p>
    </form>
    <% if session[:user] %>
        <a href="/login/sair">Sair sessão <%= @user.nome %> </a>
    <% end %>   </div> </div>
```

the login JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.message a').click(function(){
        $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

the application.js are with:

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

and also, i've been included the gem 'jquery' on my gemfile.

Nothing is happing when i click on the hiperlink "create account":
https://s13.postimg.org/8wzhw1tjr/Screenshot_20170606_224605.png

The CTRL+U on the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>V2Michel</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="D47bHUTHcwdqpFlaiDZA3LJr4236jZSSppt9q/FBwK0DPDmc76zIcsfeZSlBMFVJUNxqpFM0u/kM/AfhdNePXw==" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/fornecedors.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/home.self-d58d58b8f163d83cd8eab0042d14c22afb73ea76b61d7cd85bca19a5d2eee2ce.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/login.self-a6ac1a027c5fa2959e7c8dc0a7e2483f324f0b0833b337aa2c9560848d55a040.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/produtos.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds.self-2404dddc0e44f7051d6852d95406118fcf78ccd9df57e634c29cf011ebdb47cb.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-451e5f1e26abd1c402b1a9c60a4af0e0d30f25a334b1266b6270d9fe17346210.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-56055fe2ac3f3902deb9d12c17b2d725d432162b48fc443946daf7dfbc96d88a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-6ad2488465135ab731a045a8ebbe3ea2fc501aed286042496eda1664fdd07ba9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-742145c5bb847aafdadc6e339be795628f8bc25f177e851f03a8c42278eb0312.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-126ac9bf0e7f2d8568f8da3a00fd5f0fac6eae0946331003370161fbf8d7975e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-e47323f363ceb3dc0bdbce05e36e709ed428e339833a41140a85cb0af24b8127.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-2eb697f62b587bb786ff940d82dd4be88cdeeaf13ca128e3da3850c5fcaec301.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-561cca1cbaf67474e01e9536f106bad541594860a6df997004591c1c1957a147.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-3e78617ade5663314b7ee0ea10375a5b34d59ffbade44939e3f2a4e4ef2019b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-5bf7078b682f8b131332eefa46b45fa5eff2eca745fc0d03e2991450888f7c28.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-6d6f1a7fc5c8aabf3547fa1b794fab6268f54bc55ad815e55873c71f52513517.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-969f3c5f48cdf1e439c7fa1154c13b948715f5c689f87837c0b64521d3b46ef6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-05afb177e08f98997ccfc84fa08a215e4b27d48d5fe4d049080675e9dffd8199.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-0aa93860b59fe7393f1dd490f54b3cb994f9d6155adffce034d4e14ae361b041.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-be3674a79bb9d13d41d259b2c17fad23aef20946dab3603b9d02374ea795005f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/fornecedors.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/login.self-144986660d26a713be586866e762e4bc122ae13576cf144f04c7bf36ee4dcc31.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/produtos.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-d9c1df0d36a69bf8167ebb20070284ed3c5f931e7f6efe185b0936aad00629a6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="Senha"/>
      <button>Cadastrar</button>
      <p class="message">Já é registrado? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" action="/login/acessorecebendo" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Não está registrado <a href="#">Criar uma conta</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've deleted the attribute href on the hiperlink "create account" and Works ! lololol

Comment: Could you show the error ?

Comment: The form arent toggling her divs. I mean, did u see the effect of this JS on the link ? when u click on the hiperlink "create account" the form should do some animation and toggle to hide the form div with login informations to show up the form div with registration informations. But this arent working.. when i click, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you open your console and check if is there any error?

Comment: F12, show your console

Comment: Yes but i dint see anything wrong there.

Comment: Ok that is an start

Comment: @RamondePaulaMarques i rly dont know why this simple thing arent working xD i put a "`alert ("anything")`" after `$('.message a').click(function(){` to test my JS and the alert show as well so... i think the problem is at this line: `$('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");`

Comment: I copied that codepen code into a new html file and all worked for me, let's find a silly mistake in your code soon...

Comment: The only thing I can think right now is that there is another form in your page somewhere, maybe in your top navbar, side menu, somewhere

Comment: The JS is working on my page, so we dont have problem with that. its something wrong here: `$('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");` maybe cus a version diference of JS idk... the variable `$('form')` is getting what? i mean, the `$('.message a')` are listening for something in some tag "a" inside a .message class but the `$('form')` ?

Comment: $('form') is getting all forms in your page

Comment: and then it toggles their heights

Comment: Hmmm i know the answer

Comment: You didn't copy the css believing it wasn't needed, right? say yes hehe

Comment: @RamondePaulaMarques haha, the CSS are exactly the same ! The most stranger is: the form arent toggle the way it should be but when i click on the hiperlink "create account", the div shake a little lol

Comment: Well, i'm assuming it is a version conflict then. Remove your require jquery and include it directly in your application layout <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Nothing change but look wat i discovered: when i click on that hiperlink which start all the animation and toggle, the form div shake at the first click, shake again at the second click and do nothing after this. lol

Comment: ctrl+u copy and paste all your source code in your question

Comment: @RamondePaulaMarques I updated the post with CTRL+u

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely something messing with your assets, I copied your code and modified it to take script and style, since the ctrl+u don't bring it. It's working!

Next step you can ctrl+s in your page, save all assets together the ctrl+u and publish it somewhere, I will check it tomorrow if you want ^^

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

        .login-page {
            width: 360px;
            padding: 8% 0 0;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .form {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            max-width: 360px;
            margin: 0 auto 100px;
            padding: 45px;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
        }

        .form input {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            outline: 0;
            background: #f2f2f2;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0;
            margin: 0 0 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .form button {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            outline: 0;
            background: #4CAF50;
            width: 100%;
            border: 0;
            padding: 15px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 14px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
            transition: all 0.3 ease;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .form button:hover, .form button:active, .form button:focus {
            background: #43A047;
        }

        .form .message {
            margin: 15px 0 0;
            color: #b3b3b3;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .form .message a {
            color: #4CAF50;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .form .register-form {
            display: none;
        }

        .container {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .container:before, .container:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        .container .info {
            margin: 50px auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container .info h1 {
            margin: 0 0 15px;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 36px;
            font-weight: 300;
            color: #1a1a1a;
        }

        .container .info span {
            color: #4d4d4d;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .container .info span a {
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .container .info span .fa {
            color: #EF3B3A;
        }

        body {
            background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
            background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="Email"/>
            <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="Senha"/>
            <button>Cadastrar</button>
            <p class="message">Já é registrado? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" action="/login/acessorecebendo" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="email"/>
            <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="password"/>
            <button>login</button>
            <p class="message">Não está registrado <a href="#">Criar uma conta</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.message a').click(function () {
        $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, still with the problem xD but look something:

`Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 23:52:37 -0300
Processing by LoginController#new as HTML
  Rendering login/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered login/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 67ms (Views: 65.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

this is happening ever i click on that hiperlink

Answer (score 0):

Change your non action links from # to "javascript:;"